# DatePicker-TimePicker to a mysql timestamp

Tags: android, mysql

I have an application that uses a datepicker and a timepicker to update a mysql database that uses a timestamp type.To update the timestamp I need to use a 14 digits string like "`20110616123400`" for the year month day hours minutes seconds. So when I am calling `DatePicker.getMonth()` it will return 6 instead of 06.Is there any function that fills 0 when the month or day or hour is less than 10?

`.getMonth()` returns **1,2,...11,12** and I want to return **01,02,02...11,12**

Comment: Does android have String.slice method? Let me know

Answer (score 4):

Try using the SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

int mYear = ...
int mMonth = DatePicker.getMonth();
// ... others too...

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute);

String yourTimestamp = f.format(c.getTime();
```

You could also do it like so:

```
int mMonth = DatePicker.getMonth();
String mMonthStr = (mMonth>9) ? String.valueOf(mMonth) : "0"+mMonth;
```

Comment: thank you.I am really new in java and ignore some really basic issues

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly following query in MYSQL.

select right(concat_ws('','00',6),2); which returns 06

Answer (score 0):

use

```
String.format("%02d", num)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
for(int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
    for(int num=1;num<100;num++) {
        String text = (num < 10 ? "0" : "");
    }
}
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.println(time/99/100000);
```